# Why time.sleep doesn't work as expected within threading.Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.5.1

The `flush_worker` function is designed to generate a flush signal with interval of `60` seconds. However, the output shows that the `time.sleep` wakes up less than `1` second.

Issue1> Why does the first `sleep now` message shown without the corresponding `wake up message`

Issue2> Why does the `time.sleep` the function works only once per two cycles?

Thank you

```
def flush_worker():
    global g_flush_now
    last_flush_t = datetime.datetime.now()

    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        time_diff = (now - last_flush_t).seconds
        if time_diff >= 60:
            last_flush_t = now
            print("flush_worker: flush {0}".format(now))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            g_flush_now = True

        now_a = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("[{0}] sleep now".format(now_a))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(60)
        now_b = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("[{0}] wake up".format(now_b))
        sys.stdout.flush()

def main()        
    flush_timer = threading.Thread(target=flush_worker, daemon=True)
    flush_timer.start()

    other_function()


Output:

[2018-10-18 09:08:32.962835] sleep now                              >> why this sleep message doesn't immediately follow the wake up message?
[2018-10-18 09:08:33.824594] sleep now
[2018-10-18 09:09:32.980338] wake up                                >>> ~60 seconds gap
flush_worker: flush 2018-10-18 09:09:32.980641
[2018-10-18 09:09:32.980921] sleep now
[2018-10-18 09:09:33.830594] wake up                                >>> ~1 second gap
flush_worker: flush 2018-10-18 09:09:33.830937
[2018-10-18 09:09:33.831261] sleep now                              
[2018-10-18 09:10:33.000973] wake up                                >>> ~60 seconds gap
flush_worker: flush 2018-10-18 09:10:33.001416
[2018-10-18 09:10:33.001831] sleep now                                    
[2018-10-18 09:10:33.870503] wake up                                >>> ~1 second gap
flush_worker: flush 2018-10-18 09:10:33.870570
[2018-10-18 09:10:33.870603] sleep now
```

Comment: obligatory image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B4rVC4ICQAAr65m.jpg

Comment: I am not sure why this goes wrong, perhaps there are two threads running instead of one. However, your example is not quit complete, so I can't check...

Comment: @EvertW, my app only has one child thread shown in OP and the main process. Based on my expectation, no matter how other_function works, the time.sleep should not be affected by external threads or processes.

Comment: @q0876: you are quite right, so I am amazed you see something else. The behaviour might be explained (at least in part) if there are two threads running the same function, and the observed output originates from different threads. But lacking running code, I can not verify this...